# Similar questions overlapping on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug

See the image (using *"Simple alarm code for Android Studio"*):

[image]

It happened for only two times.

Device: [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa) 
Browser: Firefox 75

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and Firefox? [Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.10_(Eoan_Ermine)) and Firefox 75.0? No repro with said combination (though I use [Cinnamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment)) (as a workaround because [GNOME broke the clipboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188960))).

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 Firefox 75.0

Comment: Now repro after following the five steps in [the Über meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340329) (though the change to the title *may or may not* have to be done in the middle of the title, that is, not at the end). But it does not seem very reliable - is it an intermittent problem (consistent with the observation in this quesion)?